# CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions not work when binding items are created using Parallel

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library, task, collectionviewsource

I'm using VS2013, .net4.5, WPF desktop application.

**Xaml:**

```
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding ObsPasses, Mode=OneWay}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="StartDate"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

**cs:**

```
            this.ObsPasses = new ObservableCollection<PassViewModel>(
            Passes.AsParallel().Select(x => new PassViewModel(x)));
```

If I remove `.AsParallel()`, then the items are sorted, if added, the items are in disorder.
But I feel a little strange. Doesn't SortDescription **guarantee** the UI items to be sorted no matter in which order the items were added in background?

Comment: After the `ObsPasses` property is assigned all parallel operations are finished and what you are left is an `ObservableCollection` in an unknown order. There is no way it can affect the `CollectionViewSource` sorting functionality. It must be something else you're doing. Please provide _full_ verifiable sample code.

Comment: @NovitchiS after some testing on my demo project, I found **SortDescription not work no matter AsParallel or not**. So I must be wrong somewhere, but I cannot find out. [Demo](https://github.com/LeiYangGH/SortParellel)

Comment: Just an idea - have you tried to force CollectionView to refresh once collection is populated by means of View.Refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code Demo you didn't bind to CollectionViewSource, but to the collection itself. Try replacing

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ObsFoos, Mode=OneWay}" >
```

with

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" >
```

Comment: This is the only answer and I cannot delete the question with a  bounty. So accept who debugged for me. Actually I finally found it was my mistake and no relationship with Parallel or CollectionViewSource. @michauzo you pointed out a typo and it was not my first root cause. Anyway thank you!

Comment: The fault had nothing to do with any specific technology, it was a business logic issue. So you needn't be curious about it. If you want to know, see [github](https://github.com/LeiYangGH/AnyalizeTestLog/commit/b9859020952f9dfd52f8336b86bda176f591710c)

Answer (score 3):

Quick suggestion , if you can try adding IsLiveFilteringRequested="True" on your CollectionViewSource.

Let me know if it works.